# IE8 chokes on compressed CSS (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-8, sprockets

Like the title says, I'm having a problem with IE8 and compressed CSS. IE8 looks totally jacked up. *(Using Rails 3.1 with asset pipeline)*

At first I though it was the [IE 4095](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CD0QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmarc.baffl.co.uk%2Fbrowser_bugs%2Fcss-selector-limit%2Findex.html&ei=tBjvUI_gHOXL0AHluYC4DQ&usg=AFQjCNEU-7ilHSCZXUQdfuzcv0t59Da3YA&sig2=AjABM1l916pGDPERvDpQ2A&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.dmQ) bug. It turns out I only have 1034 selectors.

In production, and also after running `bundle exec rake assets precompile` locally CSS began to break.

Out of curiosity, I decompressed the CSS Rails / [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) / Asset Pipeline spit out  ..
**IE didn't break on the un-compressed version.**

Seems as though IE8 can't handle the giant compressed file.

I put a [ticket](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/402) in to see if there is an option to output both a compressed and uncompressed version, then conditionally load the uncompressed to IE.

In the meantime, I'm going to try to just turn off Rails compression for the moment.

```
config.assets.compile = false  
// in development.rb

bundle exec rake assets precompile
// assets COMPILED anyway. agghhh!
```

Sort of out of ideas. Any suggestions welcome!
Thanks!

**Edit**

Based off [this script](http://bindle.me/blog/index.php/200/splitting-the-asset-destroying-arcane-ie-bugs-on-the-rails-rack), I started writing Middleware that serves uncompressed 
CSS to IE8.

I've gotten pretty far, but noticed a lack of Ruby Gems that **decompress CSS**.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-compression => You mean `config.assets.compress` instead of `config.assets.compile` ?

Answer (score 1):

I use the `sass-rails` gem for CSS compression.

Then in production.rb:

```
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.compress = true
config.sass.style = :compressed
```

`config.assets.compile` is not doing what you expect. This actually means on-the-fly compilation, not pre-compilation. `config.assets.compress` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  The only work around is to break out your compressed javascript into more than one file.  I ended up breaking up my scripts into two different compressed files.  This fixed the issue.

Hope that helps.